# Bash: Loop with if-statement

Tags: string, bash, loops, if-statement

In my bash script, I have a loop over files in a directory and a simple if-statement to filter for specific files. However, it does not behave as I expect, but I don't see why.

(I know I could filter for file extensions already in the for-loop expression (`... in "*.txt"`), but the condition is more complex in my actual case.)

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "*"
do
    echo $f
    if [[ $f == *"txt" ]]
    then
        echo "yes"
    else
        echo "no"
    fi
done
```

The output I get:

```
1001.txt 1002.txt 1003.txt files.csv
no
```

What I would expect:

```
1001.txt 
yes
1002.txt 
yes
1003.txt 
yes
files.csv 
no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misquoted problem in your script. You have an additional quoting at top in `glob` and missing a quote in `echo`.

Have it this way:

```
for f in *
do
    echo "$f"
    if [[ $f == *"txt" ]]
    then
        echo "yes"
    else
        echo "no"
    fi
done
```

- `for f in "*"` will loop only once with `f` as literal `*`
- Unquoted `echo $f` will expand `*` to output all the matching files/directories in the current directory.